# AttributeError: module 'curses' has no attribute 'A_ITALIC'

Tags: python, ncurses, curses

For some reason, I cannot for the life of me figure out why curses won't let me use the `A_ITALIC` attribute.

All of the other attributes seem to work with no issues, but italic specifically triggers an error message.

I'm running Python 3.10.4, here's some sample code:

```
import curses

def main(stdscr):
    stdscr.addstr(0, 0, "This should be italicized!", curses.A_ITALIC)
    stdscr.getch()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    curses.wrapper(main)
```

Comment: Are you certain that you're running python 3.10? Could it be that you have multiple Python versions installed and running a different one?

Comment: `print(dir(curses))`

Comment: @WasiMaster I am for sure running 3.10, because my code also uses the new `match` statement added in 3.10 and that works fine. My installation is from brew.

Comment: @JacobIRR That's very cool, wasn't aware I could do this. Definitely do not have A_ITALIC in my version of curses.

Answer (score 2):

Python on MacOS could support `A_ITALIC` if it is built using a recent version of ncurses (since [2013](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t20130831), e.g., ncurses 6.x).  The system version of ncurses for MacOS is far too old for that.

The same applies to Python on other platforms, e.g., [NetBSD](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/lib/libcurses/curses.h?only_with_tag=MAIN) and legacy Unix systems.

With correspondingly recent versions of Python, you can check which version of ncurses using the [`version`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.version) or the [`ncurses_version`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.ncurses_version) function.  However, even with a recent ncurses version, there's always the possibility of a bug in Python which interferes with providing that feature.

Python's curses wrapper (see [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/87b9b4e060377f09096db7af977f604749c8a100/Modules/_cursesmodule.c#L4853)) knows about the feature because its name is compiled-in when Python is built:

```
    /* ncurses extension */
#ifdef A_ITALIC
    SetDictInt("A_ITALIC",          A_ITALIC);
#endif
```

Changing the underlying ncurses would not affect that (unless Python is rebuilt).

Comment: Is there any way to update my version of ncurses or am I locked into it until it gets updated with the system?

Comment: MacPorts and brew provide newer packages for MacOS.  If you wait for Apple to update the system, it'll be a long wait.

Comment: brew claims that I have the latest version of ncurses, 6.3

Comment: I found what I believe is your website with links to download the newest version of ncurses, do you happen to know if it's possible to update the version of curses I have in python? I can't seem to find any resources about it online

Comment: The Python curses wrapper uses a shared library which is compiled when the python package is built (and that determines whether `A_ITALIC` is supported).  Python is about 485,000 lines of C (probably not that simple to rebuild it).

Comment: Yikes. Well, thank you for the help. I will deal with it for now until it (eventually) gets updated!

Answer (score 1):

From [the `curses` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html):

> The exact constants available are system dependent.

I tried it in Python 3.9.12 on macOS, and it didn't work, but it did work using Python 3.10.4 in a Docker container.

Comment: Also it says that `A_ITALIC` was added in 3.7.

Comment: Well that's frustrating. I guess I can wrap every call to A_ITALIC in a try/except but that's such a hassle and not nice looking.