# Color palette and more scale variations

Tags: perl, ncurses, curses

I have here two code so you can help me understand...
Well at first my mask colors the "loading" shape. The initials `rgbkmcw` indicate their colors, red, ..., white. These are normal, already the CAPITAL LETTERS, correspond to bold `(red = \e[31;10m; RED = \e[31;1m)`.
What I'm looking for is more variety of colors. Searching I found many, as well as for cyan.
`cyan = "\e[36;10m",  normal`
`cyann = "\e[36;1m",  bold`
`cyanf = "\e[36;2m",  weak`
`cyani = "\e[36;3m",  italic`
`cyans = "\e[36;4m",  underscore`
`cyanp = "\e[36;5m",  flashing`
`cyanb = "\e[36;7m",  background`
`cyanc = "\e[36;9m",  canceled`

How to use one of these colors in the mask abbreviating to some letter or number? Since everyady the each character in the mask represents the color of the corresponding character in the object.
For example: you want to use cyan italic; cyan normal and bold are already defined with c and C in the Term::Animation module.

So when trying to do 'ci' and run perl; return -> `Use uninitialized value in stanza entry in /usr/local/share/perl/5.34.0/Term/Animation.pm`
Why is there no italic cyan (ci) defined. I went to `cd usr/local/share/perl/5.34.0/Term/Animation.pm`
And there it creates lists mapping full color names (e.g. 'blue') and single character color IDs (e.g. 'b')

```
#---------- cd usr/local/share/perl/5.34.0/Term/----------
sub _color_list {
        my %color_n;
        my %color_i = (
                black   => 'k',
                white   => 'w',
                red     => 'r',
                green   => 'g',
                blue    => 'b',
                cyan    => 'c',
                magenta => 'm',
                yellow  => 'y',
        );

        for (keys %color_i) {
                $color_i{uc($_)} = uc($color_i{$_});
        }
        for (keys %color_i) {
                $color_n{$color_i{$_}} = $_;
                $color_n{$_} = $_;
                $color_n{uc($_)} = uc($_);
        }    
        for(qw{ k w r g b c m y }) {
                $color_i{$_} = $_;
                $color_i{uc($_)} = uc($_);
        }    
        return (\%color_n, \%color_i);
}
```

I need to include more color variations, like this [color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ew5T.png).
So, how to add directly in the Animation.pm module, a color like cyan italic = `\e[36;3m;` ?
I tried querying the Term::Animation/COLOR section in [link metacpan](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::Animation::Entity) but the page returns "Not Found".

```
#---------------------MY MASK--------------------------  
use strict;
use warnings;
# you don't have to include Curses, but it is handy so we
# can use halfdelay and getch below.
use Curses;
use Term::Animation 2.0;
# this creates a full screen animation object. you can also
# pass a curses window as an argument to new()
my $s = Term::Animation->new();

$s->color(1);
my $phrase = "Press q to exit";
# a few simple ASCII art objects to move around

my @loading= (q{
================
});
my @mask = (q{
RrBbWwKkYyMmCcGg
});
$s->new_entity(
        shape           => \@loading,
        position        => [ 30, 2, 20],
        callback_args   => [0,0,0,1],
        color   => \@mask,
);
halfdelay( 2 );
for(1..500) {

$s->animate();
my $in = lc( getch() );
if($in eq 'q') { last; }
}
```

---

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $cyan  = "\e[36;10m";#normal
my $cyann = "\e[36;1m"; #bold
my $cyanf = "\e[36;2m"; #weak

my $off = "\e[m";       #off

say("$cyan    cyan   $off");
say("$cyann   cyann  $off");
say("$cyanf   cyanf  $off");
```

Comment: The [list of colors](https://metacpan.org/dist/Term-Animation/source/lib/Term/Animation.pm#L194) in the module, which you nicely show in the question, appears to be it.  Even [their docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::Animation) say "_The available colors are: red, green, blue, cyan, magenta, yellow, black and white._".   (One _can_ poke at a library internals and patch it up at runtime but that's not a simple task)

Comment: *"I tried querying the Term::Animation/COLOR section in link metacpan but the page returns "Not Found""* Yes, there seems to be a Pod error. I think it should link to this section: https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::Animation#COLOR

Comment: *"For example: you want to use cyan italic"* : Seems like italics was something that was added more recently to ncurses, see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72308765/2173773. The Perl module might not be up-to-date here.

Comment: *"The Perl module might not be up-to-date here"* Though, it appears to be quite simple to add support for `A_ITALIC` to [Curses](https://metacpan.org/pod/Curses). I tried the following, which seems to work: https://github.com/hakonhagland/perl-curses/commit/5b6cc0e988b5d1ffb4ea5ce4833efeceef4decf1. I will test next if this change in `Curses` can be applied to your specific use case of `Term::Animation`

Comment: people, don't limit yourself to italics, for example: the [color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ew5T.png)  \x1b[48;5;81m = to number 81 of the image

Comment: *"I will test next if this change in Curses can be applied to your specific use case"*: I was able to apply it after a modification to [Term::Animation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::Animation) source code. See this example: https://github.com/hakonhagland/perl-term-animation/commit/571d10a8fdbcea557f3880f57fdc912f8b374279. Using this example, you define a `color2` mask in addition to your `color` mask in your Perl script. The `color2` mask defines whether a character is italics or not

Comment: @HåkonHægland  actually I need the color 16, ..., 255. for example: the [color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ew5T.png) \x1b48;5;21m = the number 81 of the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ew5T.png)

Comment: @Cmistry *"I need the color 16, ..., 255."* I am not sure if curses support those. According to this article, it only supports 8 colors at the same time: https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/about-ncurses-colors-0, but those 8 colors might be redefined using `init_color`, see: https://linux.die.net/man/3/init_color

Comment: @Cmistry *"ncurses only supports 8 colors at the same time"* There might be a solution by recompiling ncurses with a special flag, see: https://c-for-dummies.com/ncurses/original/256color.php. This could give you all the 256 colors

Comment: @Cmistry *"ncurses only supports 8 colors at the same time"* That might not be correct, I did some more testing and it seems you can get up to 256 foreground colors by using `init_pair` with an index greater than 7: https://linux.die.net/man/3/init_pair. I will do some more testing

Comment: *"I will do some more testing"* : Yes this works with a small modification to the source of `Term::Animation`. Here is an example: https://github.com/hakonhagland/perl-term-animation/commit/5da8a53c58d173541043f7c24db2ecbd5e661625. With this modification you define a `color2` mask instead of a `color` mask in your perl script. In this mask `a` is color #1, `b` is color #2, `c` is color number #3, and so on

Comment: @HåkonHægland Hi, very good. It may not be the 256 colors, but 'a'..'z' are enough colors. can you answer my question outside the comments for me to mark as correct with an example just like you did for  [natural.pl](https://github.com/hakonhagland/perl-term-animation/blob/5da8a53c58d173541043f7c24db2ecbd5e661625/examples/color_nature.pl)
because I copied and pasted the modified module and when running perl mask.pl it doesn't show me anything.

Comment: *"can you answer my question outside the comments"* Yes, I will clean up the code a little bit first.

Comment: Added ticket requesting support for italics in `Curses` module: https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=146942

Comment: Added ticket for requesting extended color support in the `Term::Animation` module: https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=146944

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to use one of these colors in the mask abbreviating to some letter or number?

Currently `Term::Animation` only supports 8 colors, so you need to modify the source to do this. Here is an example:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/hakonhagland/perl-term-animation.git 
$ cd perl-term-animation/
$ git fetch origin colors:colors
$ git checkout colors
$ cpanm --installdeps .
$ perl Makefile.PL
$ make
$ make test
$ make install  # <- or use "sudo make install" if you are using the system perl
```

A simple test program to test the modified `Term::Animation` module:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Curses;
use Term::Animation 2.0;

my $s = Term::Animation->new();
$s->color2(1);  # <-- uses the color2 type mask
my @loading= (q{
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
});
my @mask = (q{
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
});

$s->new_entity(
        shape           => \@loading,
        position        => [ 30, 2, 20],
        callback_args   => [0,0,0,1],
        color   => \@mask,
);
halfdelay( 2 );
for(1..500) {
    $s->animate();
    my $in = lc( getch() );
    if($in eq 'q') { last; }
}
```

With this test program I get the following output (screen shot):

[image]

Comment: thank you, your module is good and easy to understand.
Effective for my game designs. you have talent, congratulations.

Comment: Hi, it's me again k.
I went to test the colors and realized that if you add spaces in the corresponding image with the mask. error messages appear :( notice, I added a space between the B and the C [img](https://i.imgur.com/5fHU8lV.jpg)

Comment: Hi Cmistry. Thanks for the report. I fixed the bug, see the last commit: https://github.com/hakonhagland/perl-term-animation/commit/584fc9af438fa5632eccc785701a0ef3bca05ce2

Comment: What's wrong with default_color?

Comment: Hi. Can you give some more information about the problem you have?

Comment: everything works ok when I only use ```color```, but when I provide a default color with the ```default_color``` parameter.
for the entire entity to be a single color. An error like the one above appears.

Comment: I see. Can you try with the last commit: https://github.com/hakonhagland/perl-term-animation/commit/29496375d7841a63ff4a6708ca79a0879d226f8a

Comment: Only yourself, to understand your module.
I modified the code exactly as in the example.
error persists.
I even had added capital letters and numbers 'A..Z','0..9', inside the module for more options. but I settle for using $s->color(1); Because it won't be very useful color(2); with inoperable default_color.
Even so the previous version is still very useful to me.
The tools your template provides are  yes easy to use for a beginner like me. But I find it a bit difficult to directly interpret the module to make a value change, such as a color change.

Comment: *"I modified the code exactly as in the example. error persists."* Maybe you could send me the code you are using? Then I can check if I get the same error?

Comment: *"But I find it a bit difficult to directly interpret the module to make a value change, such as a color change"* You mean change one color to a different value? For example change red to orange?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using the translator.
It is working exactly as expected. except default_color parameter. so that the entire entity is a single color.
[Animation.pm](https://pastebin.com/jdg9T9VY) and [test.pl](https://pastebin.com/JVyEw23B)

Comment: Can you try with the latest commit: https://github.com/hakonhagland/perl-term-animation/commit/43d42d31ef476d26d13163485de765a83a186abe. When I use your `test.pl` I get no errors with this change

Answer (score 2):

My [Antsy](https://metacpan.org/pod/Antsy) module handles almost everything that iTerm2 lets me do. Even if you don't want to use it, looking inside should show you most things ANSI terminals are expected to handle (even if they don't). For example, I can specify one of 256 colors with 24-bit RGB values.

Also look at [Term::ANSIColor](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ANSIColor) and the [ANSI escapes](https://notes.burke.libbey.me/ansi-escape-codes/).

Comment: I don't understand your module. so how would [color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ew5T.png) 28, ..., 39. In my [mask](http://tpcg.io/_32F8LS) `RrBbWwKkYyMmCcGg`? Remembering that each character in the mask represents the color of the corresponding character in the object. \x1b[48;5;81m = to number 81 of the link color